# Schema validation with XML (element and attribute)

Tags: xml, schema

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <catalog xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       xmlns:x="urn:book"> 
  <!-- START OF SCHEMA -->
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:book">
   <xsd:element name="book">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:float"/>
      <xsd:element name="publish_date" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>

  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<!-- END OF SCHEMA -->
   <x:book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price currency="USD">44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description lan="ENG">An in-depth look at creating applications with
      XML.</description>
   </x:book>
</catalog>
```

Hi would someone mind to enlight me on high to declare the attribute inside price and           description element? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
      <xsd:element name="description">
        <xsd:attribute name="gender">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xsd:pattern value="male|female"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
      </xsd:element>
```